# Atomic Update in MS Velocity

Tags: memcached, appfabric

Does Velocity support server-side atomic updates ? 
I'm trying to see if i can port some code (based on memcached) which implemented a ring  buffer based on memcache's INCR operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't say that I'm familiar enough with memcached to know *exactly* what you mean, but I'm assuming that it involves locking a cached item so that one client can update it, which is supported by Velocity through the [GetAndLock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.data.caching.datacache.getandlock.aspx) and [PutAndUnlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.data.caching.datacache.putandunlock.aspx) methods.

Edit: OK, now I understand what you mean, no I haven't seen anything like that in Velocity. But you could write it as an extension method e.g.

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Public Module VelocityExtensions

<Extension()> _
Public Sub Increment(ByVal cache As Microsoft.Data.Caching.DataCache, ByVal itemKey As String)

    Dim cachedInteger As Integer
    Dim cacheLockHandle As DataCacheLockHandle

    cachedInteger = DirectCast(cache.GetAndLock(itemKey, New TimeSpan(0, 0, 5), cacheLockHandle), Integer)

    cachedInteger += 1

    cache.PutAndUnlock(itemKey, cachedInteger, cacheLockHandle)

End Sub

<Extension()> _
Public Sub Decrement(ByVal cache As Microsoft.Data.Caching.DataCache, ByVal itemKey As String)

    Dim cachedInteger As Integer
    Dim cacheLockHandle As DataCacheLockHandle

    cachedInteger = DirectCast(cache.GetAndLock(itemKey, New TimeSpan(0, 0, 5), cacheLockHandle), Integer)

    cachedInteger -= 1

    cache.PutAndUnlock(itemKey, cachedInteger, cacheLockHandle)

End Sub

End Module
```

Your usage would then become:

```
Imports VelocityExtensions
Imports Microsoft.Data.Caching

Partial Public Class _Default
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim myCache As DataCache
    Dim factory As DataCacheFactory

    myCache = factory.GetCache("MyCacheName")

    myCache.Increment("MyInteger")

End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: In memcached you can do atomic increments and decrements in a single server roundtrip. For example, i can do a client.Increment("totalViews-" + contentId), which does the lock/increment/unlock on the server in one go.

Comment: Thanks for that, Phil. It definitely works, though not as efficient as id like.

Comment: This solution wouldn't work because the second call to the lock will fail.

Comment: By failure I mean that request won't be blocked which will create miss update problem. Link here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd631073.aspx